# Java Lambda Reading S3 webpage instead of s3object i.e s3 file

Tags: java, html, file, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have written a Lambda in Java 11 for reading word(docx) file(s3 objects) from s3. But my lambda is not reading the file instead it is reading the S3 web page … The output looks encrypted which has all unicode characters and some words like footnotes.xml, settings.xml etc… How can I actually read from the file placed on s3?

Java version on AWS Lambda - 11(corretto)
Aws sdk - 1.11.937

Answer (score 0):

Use the AWS SDK for Java to create an S3 client and call the getObject API method

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html#download-object